# Calling a function in the page constructor results in empty array

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic2

I try to load and bind `this.studentNames[i].checked` to prepare checkboxes (key-value pair in localstorage if checkbox is set). However, after correctly pushing the entries from the storage in the `this.studentNames` array (I can see all of them as in the storage in the view), the this.studentNames array is then empty [] in the array and hence not longer accessable for the model.

Do I use this here in a wrong way? I thought, when I use `=>`functions, erverything should be ok?!

**My view (HTML)**:

```
<ion-list>
  <ion-item *ngFor="let studentName of studentNames; let i=index">
    <ion-label>{{studentName.name}}</ion-label>
    <ion-checkbox [(ngModel)]="studentName.checked" (ionChange)="checkboxToggle($event,studentName)"></ion-checkbox>
  </ion-item>
</ion-list>
```

**My model (TypeScript)**:

```
@mycomp...
selectedItem: any;
studentNames: Array<{id: string, name: string, checked: boolean}>;

constructor(private navParams: NavParams, public storage: Storage) {
    // If we navigated to this page, we will have an item available as a nav param
    this.selectedItem = navParams.get('item');
    this.studentNames = [];
    this.readStorageAtStartup();
    console.log(this.studentNames)
  }

  public readStorageAtStartup() {
    this.storage.ready().then(() => {
       this.storage.forEach( (value: string, key: string, index: number) => {
         if(key.charAt(0)=="S") {
           this.studentNames.push({id: key, name: value, checked: true})
         }
       })
    })
  }
```

**Console.log() (Firefox)**:

```
Array [  ]
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: The `readIsCheckedAtStartup();` call is commented, so in the posted code it's not being called at all (and thus, the `index2 ` is not being initialized)... I don't fully understand what the issue would be

Comment: @sebaferreras Thanks, that was for debugging, but when I remove the comment it sais this.studentNames undefined and index2 is hence -1... My problem is that (already in the first function) this.studentName is empty array [] in the model (please see the output above), but I can see the entries in the view.

Comment: @sebaferreras I edited the question, so I hope it's much clearer now.

Comment: `this.storage.ready()` is asynchronous, so you can't depend on `this.studentNames` being populated after the `readStorageAtStartup` call. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan Many thanks, that's a load of input for me to check. :). So I think my question is relevant, could you please upvote if so? Sorry for asking but I don't want to get stuck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass the storage as a parameter into your readStorageAtStartup function and resolve the asynchronous request from there

```
public readStorageAtStartup(storage: Storage) {
storage.ready().then(() => {
   storage.forEach( (value: string, key: string, index: number) => {
     if(key.charAt(0)=="S") {
       this.studentNames.push({id: key, name: value, checked: true})
     }
   })
})
```

}